# Rombo de caracteres "+"

Tags: javascript

Hoy he estado dándole una vuelta a los bucles e intentando hacer una variación del típico rombo de caracteres con js, pero me he atrancado y no veo salida.

No quiero utilizar métodos, ni nada por el estilo, y no consigo hacer la parte invertida, la parte superior esta como quiero pero la inferior (invertida) no la saco ni soñando...
por cierto la idea es que empiece por 4 no por 1.

```js
let dimension1 = 4
let dimension2 = 10
let total = "";
let space = dimension1 - 1;
   
for (let i = 0; i < (dimension1 * 2) - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < space; j++) {
        total += ' ';   
    }
    space--
    for (let j = 0; j < dimension1 + (i * 2); j++) {
        total += '+';  
    }
    total += '\n'
}
    
for (let i = dimension2; i < (dimension1 * 2) - 1; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < space + 1; j++) {
        total += '-';    
    }
    space++
    for (let j = 0; j < dimension2 + (i / 2); j--) {
        total += '+';            
    }
    total += '\n'
}
alert(total)
```

Comment: Buen día, según entiendo quieres hacer un rombo empezando con 4 signos "+" en la parte superior y en la mitad debería ser de 10 ¿Correcto? ¿El incremento de cada fila es 2 signos "+"? ¿En la mitad debe haber dos filas con 10 "+", o debe haber una?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato buenas, todo correcto, excepto la pregunta final, en el centro una única fila de 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay un pequeño problema con tus ciclos `for`, para hacer el rombo debes iniciar en el valor mínimo y terminar en el valor máximo para hacer la parte superior y empezar en el valor máximo - 2 y terminar en el valor mínimo para la parte inferior

Ejemplo:

```js
let dimension1 = 4
let dimension2 = 10
let total = "";
let space = dimension1 - 1;

// Creamos la parte superior desde dimension1 hasta dimension2, pero incrementamos de 2 en 2
for (let i = dimension1; i <= (dimension2); i += 2){
        // Dibujamos los espacios en cada ciclo
        for (let j = 0; j < space; j++){
            total += ' ';
    }
    // Decrementamos la variable de espacios
    space--;
    // Dibujamos los "+" desde 0 hasta el valor actual de i, que sería desde dimension1 hasta dimension2
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++){
            total += '+';
    }
    // Insertamos un salto de línea
    total += '\n'
}
// Inicializamos la variable de espacios en 1 ya que la parte inferior requiere un espacio en el ciclo inicial
space = 1;
// Dibujamos la parte inferior desde dimension2-2 hasta dimension1 pero decrementamos de 2 en 2
for (let i = dimension2-2; i >= (dimension1); i -= 2){
        // Dibujamos los espacios en cada ciclo
        for (let j = 0; j < space; j++){
            total += ' ';
    }
    // Incrementamos la variable de espacios
    space++;
    // Dibujamos los "+" desde 0 hasta el valor actual de i, que sería desde dimension2 hasta dimension1
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++){
            total += '+';
    }
    total += '\n'
}
// Dibujamos el rombo
alert(total)
```

Comment: ahhhh vale! gracias.
Me cuesta mucho los bucles y por más que leo y hago no termina la lógica de calar en mi mente.

Comment: Cuando tengas que hacer un ciclo es más fácil si dices en voz alta lo que quieres hacer, por ejemplo, dibujar desde 4 hasta 10, o dibujar desde 8 hasta 4, al decirlo en voz alta muchas veces es más fácil encontrar los límites y el incremento.

Comment: Puede que en alert no se vea bien, como es mí caso. Pero con console.log sí.

Comment: Tu ejemplo sólo vale para los valores 4 y 10, eso no es muy extensible que digamos. Puedes ver tu código [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/virtual_kur2/ba0mq1j3/) donde he variado las dimensiones a 3 y 10 respectivamente, y [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/virtual_kur2/ba0mq1j3/3/) donde las he variado a 5 y 11. Yo elaboraría un poco más la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo con 1 solo bucle `for` y calculando el *padding* de cada linea sería la siguiente:

```js
const rombos = [
  [4, 10, '+', ' '],
  [2, 8, '+', ' '],
  [1, 3, '+', ' '],
  [3, 1, '+', ' ']
];

const paintRombo = (start, end, symbol, spacer) => {
  if (start === end) return;
  if (start < 0 || end < 0) return;
  if(symbol.length !== 1 || spacer.length !== 1) return;
  if (end < start)
  {
    let temp = start;
    start = end;
    end = temp;
  }
  let rows = end - start;
  if(rows < 2) return;
  
  let mid = parseInt(rows / 2);
  if(rows % 2 !== 0) {
    rows++;
    mid++;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i <= rows; ++i) {
    let symbolPart = '';
    let paddedPart = '';
    let line = '';
    
    let pad = (end - start - (i * 2)) / 2;
    if(pad < 0){
      pad *= -1;
    }
    for(j = 0; j < pad; ++j) {
      paddedPart += spacer;
    }
    
    const increment = i <= rows / 2 ? (2 * i) + start : end - ((i - mid) * 2);
    
    for(j = 0; j < increment; ++j) {
      symbolPart += '+';
    }
    line = paddedPart + symbolPart + paddedPart;
    console.log(line);
  }
}

rombos.forEach(rombo => {
  paintRombo(...rombo);
  console.log('');
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar se construye la parte que hará de *padding* inicial y final en cada iteración.

Para calcular el incremento o decremento se aprovechan las matemáticas, así en una sola iteración se obtiene tanto la parte que permite el crecimiento de la cantidad de símbolos hasta la mitad del rombo y la parte que implica el decrecimiento de los símbolos a partir de la mitad.

En un solo bucle `for` se incluyen 2 bucles `for` anidados para poder completar la parte de la linea que corresponde al *padding* como la parte de la linea que corresponde a los símbolos.

Luego se une todo en una sola variable llamada linea y tienes el resultado esperado.

He creado una función que recibe el valor de `start` y `end`, que representarían el tamaño inicial del rombo (extremo) y el tamaño final del mismo (centro). También reciben por parámetro el símbolo que quieres para dibujar el rombo y el carácter espaciador.

Además he puesto algunas comprobaciones para evitar dibujar rombos con parámetros no válidos.

Supongamos que en vez de usar un bucle para construir la parte de símbolos y la parte de *padding*, podemos usar el método [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), el código anterior se vería un poquito más limpio así:

```js
const rombos = [
  [4, 10, '@', ' '],
  [2, 8, '@', ' '],
  [1, 3, '@', ' '],
  [3, 1, '@', ' ']
];

const paintRombo = (start, end, symbol, spacer) => {
  if (start === end) return;
  if (start < 0 || end < 0) return;
  if(symbol.length !== 1 || spacer.length !== 1) return;
  if (end < start)
  {
    let temp = start;
    start = end;
    end = temp;
  }
  let rows = end - start;
  if(rows < 2) return;
  
  let mid = parseInt(rows / 2);
  if(rows % 2 !== 0) {
    rows++;
    mid++;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i <= rows; ++i) {
    
    let pad = (end - start - (i * 2)) / 2;
    if(pad < 0){
      pad *= -1;
    }
    const paddedPart = spacer.repeat(pad);
    
    const increment = i <= rows / 2 ? (2 * i) + start : end - ((i - mid) * 2);
    const symbolPart = symbol.repeat(increment);
    
    const line = paddedPart + symbolPart + paddedPart;
    console.log(line);
  }
}

rombos.forEach(rombo => {
  paintRombo(...rombo);
  console.log('');
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Explicación para el cálculo del incremento y del padding**

El cálculo del *padding* es trivial, a medida que aumenta el iterador `i`, calculamos el valor (`pad`) usando la siguiente fórmula:

```js
let pad = (end - start - (i * 2)) / 2;
```

Si corremos un bucle mostrando este resultado, obtenemos lo siguiente:

```js
const start = 4;
const end = 10;
for(let i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
  console.log(`pad: ${(end - start - (i * 2)) / 2}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa el valor de `pad` se hace negativo justo a partir de la mitad del ciclo, es por ello que basta con multiplicarlo por `-1` cuando se detecta que es negativo:

```js
const start = 4;
const end = 10;
for(let i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
  let pad = (end - start - (i * 2)) / 2;
  if (pad < 0) {
    pad *= -1;
  }
  console.log(`pad: ${pad}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Para el cálculo del incremento, hay que pensar un poquito en cómo trabajar con el iterador que siempre está creciendo. Es por ello que se calcula una variable llamada `mid`. Si observamos el código y entendiendo la geometría del rombo, la cantidad de lineas dibujadas será siempre impar, por lo tanto si queremos saber cuál será el número de linea que corresponde a la mitad del rombo debemos calcular la parte entera de la división de la cantidad de lineas por dibujar.

En el ejemplo de tu pregunta, la cantidad de lineas calculada mediante `end - start` nos da un número par, por lo cual podemos calcular sin problema su mitad, sin embargo para casos impares esto no da el valor exacto, así que se procede a añadir una linea adicional tanto al número de filas que se van a recorrer como al valor calculado para la mitad.

Esto tiene una explicación geométrica, para la cual no daré más detalles, pero una vez calculado el número de lineas y el valor posicional de la linea central, es fácil usar el iterador para calcular el número de veces que debe aparecer el símbolo en la linea correspondiente.

Para la primera mitad (mitad superior) simplemente hacemos:

```js
let increment = (2 * i) + start;
```

Y para la mitad inferior hacemos:

```js
let increment = end - ((i - mid) * 2);
```

Para combinar esto en una sola linea podemos usar el operador ternario, tal como lo hemos hecho en nuestra función:

```js
const increment = i <= rows / 2 ? (2 * i) + start : end - ((i - mid) * 2);
```

Para mostrar el comportamiento de esta variable podemos ver el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
const start = 4;
const end = 10;
let rows = end -start;
let mid = parseInt(rows / 2);
if(rows % 2 !== 0) {
  rows++;
  mid++;
}

for(let i = 0; i <= rows; ++i) {
  const increment = i <= mid ? (2 * i) + start : end - ((i - mid) * 2);
  console.log(increment);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa, en la iteración `i = 3` se alcanza el máximo valor (`end`) para la cantidad de símbolos que tendrá nuestro rombo, es la linea central, y a partir de allí su valor decrece de la misma forma en como ha crecido. Esto nos permite calcular el incremento sin importar el tamaño del rombo.

Comment: Excelente explicación, muchas gracias!